# Kivy - Timer Integration in FloatLayout

Tags: python, layout, timer, kivy, kivy-language

The issue is a simple one, getting Kivy to integrate the Timer1 code as a label in *FloatLayout*.

I have this .py file:

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from digitalclock import DigitalClock
from kivy.animation import Animation

import time


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


backbone = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class Status(FloatLayout):
    _change = StringProperty()
    _tnd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self._change = str(self.time)
        self._tnd.text = str(self.time)
        print (self._change)


class Timer1(Label):
    a = NumericProperty(10)  # seconds
    color = 1, 1, 1, 1
    font_size = 50

    def start(self):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)  # stop any current animations
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)

        def finish_callback(animation, incr_crude_clock):
            incr_crude_clock.text = "COOL"
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=finish_callback)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        self.text = str(round(value, 1))


class XGApp(App):
    time = StringProperty()

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = str(time.asctime())

    def build (self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        t1 = Timer1()
        return backbone


xApp = XGApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xApp.run()
```

**and the .kv:**

```
<ContScreen>:
    DigitalClock:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.075, 0.075)

    StackLayout
        orientation: "tb-rl"
        spacing: 15

        Button:
            text: "1"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
            on_press:
                self.background_color = (1.7, 0, 1.7, 1)
                t1.start()
```

I am trying to get the Timer1 aspect as a label in *FloatLayout* on the .kv, which appears as the button is triggered. At the moment, what I've been getting is the Timer1 as a full-screen label.

Please help!

Comment: what is `t1`???

Comment: If you scroll down on the .py, t1 is defined as the Timer1 class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. Move the design view of Timer's Label from Python code into kv file.
2. Add constructor for *class Timer* and accepts arguments, `root, instance, duration, bg_colour`
3. In kv file, pass arguments *root (screen 'cont'), instance of button, duration, background colour* when instantiating *Timer*
4. In *build* method, remove `t1 = Timer1()`

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation

import time


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Status(FloatLayout):
    _change = StringProperty()
    _tnd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self._change = str(self.time)
        self._tnd.text = str(self.time)
        print (self._change)


class Timer(Label):
    a = NumericProperty()  # seconds

    def __init__(self, root, instance, duration, bg_colour, **kwargs):
        super(Timer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = instance
        self.a = duration
        self.root = root

        self.obj.disabled = True    # disable widget/button
        self.obj.background_color = bg_colour
        self.root.add_widget(self)  # add Timer/Label widget to screen, 'cont'

    def animation_complete(self, animation, widget):
        self.root.remove_widget(widget)  # remove Timer/Label widget to screen, 'cont'
        self.obj.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # reset to default colour
        self.obj.disabled = False   # enable widget/button

    def start(self):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)  # stop any current animations
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.animation_complete)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        self.text = str(round(value, 1))


class XGApp(App):
    time = StringProperty()

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = str(time.asctime())

    def build (self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    XGApp().run()
```

### kv file

```
#:import DigitalClock digitalclock
#:import Timer main.Timer

<ContScreen>:
    DigitalClock:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.075, 0.075)

    StackLayout
        orientation: "tb-rl"
        spacing: 15

        Button:
            text: "1"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
            on_press:
                Timer(root, self, 5, [0.17, 1.7, 0, 1]).start()

        Button:
            text: "2"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
            on_press:
                Timer(root, self, 10, [1.7, 0, 1.7, 1]).start()


<Timer>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0.5, 1  # 50% blue
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    size_hint: 0.3, .1
    font_size: 50
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Button 1 pressed]
[image: Img02 - Button 2 pressed]

Comment: Flawless work again ikolim, I invite you to try my last open question on this program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447113/controlling-arduino-gpio-from-raspberry-pi

Comment: Accompanied by this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487163/kivy-label-to-display-real-time-sensor-data

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it work is to have the `Button` create the timer. Start by adding a `start_timer()` method to the `ContScreen` class:

```
class ContScreen(Screen):
    def start_timer(self, *args):
        timer = Timer1(size_hint=(0.2, 0.2))
        self.add_widget(timer)
        timer.start()
```

For this to work, make three other changes:

1. Change your `main.kv` file to make a root widget (eliminate the `<>` surrounding `ContScreen`).
2. Change the `on_press` for the button in the `.kv` file by replacing `t1.start()` with `root.start_timer()`.
3. Eliminate the `t1 = Timer1()` statement from your `build` method in the `XGApp` class.

Another approach would be to create the `Timer1` in the `.kv` file, and just start it running when the `Button` is pressed. To do this, change your `.kv` file to include a `Timer`:

```
ContScreen:
    DigitalClock:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.9}
        size_hint: (0.075, 0.075)

    StackLayout
        orientation: "tb-rl"
        spacing: 15

        Button:
            text: "1"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
            on_press:
                self.background_color = (1.7, 0, 1.7, 1)
                timer.start()

        Timer1:
            id: timer
            text: '0.0'
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
```

Move your `backbone = Builder.load_file("main.kv")` to after the definition of the `Timer1` class. And change the `ContScreen` class back to:

```
class ContScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

Comment: Can you describe the process for creating Timer1 in the .kv? I will try both methods.

Comment: Added that info to my answer.