# Kivy - Label to display real-time Sensor Data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, temp

I would like to create two labels in Kivy that update their text with sensor data from temp sensors.

Temp sensors are connected to an Arduino, which prints their values to serial in the example format every two seconds or so:

A 82.4 *(on line 1)*

B 80.6 *(on line 2)*

The A/B is included in each print as an identifier that python could pick up to differentiate between the two.

The issue is importing this data into python and attaching it to labels.

**Here is the existing .py:**

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from digitalclock import DigitalClock
from kivy.animation import Animation

import serial
import time
import opc


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


#Disregard this, a timer is included in layout
class Timer(Label):
    a = NumericProperty()  # seconds

    def __init__(self, root, instance, duration, bg_color, **kwargs):
        super(Timer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = instance
        self.a = duration
        self.root = root

        self.obj.disabled = True    # disable widget/button
        self.obj.background_color = bg_color
        self.root.add_widget(self)  # add Timer/Label widget to screen, 'cont'

    def animation_complete(self, animation, widget):
        self.root.remove_widget(widget)  # remove Timer/Label widget to screen, 'cont'
        self.obj.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # reset to default colour
        self.obj.disabled = False   # enable widget/button

    def start(self):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)  # stop any current animations
        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.animation_complete)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        self.text = str(round(value, 1))


class Status(FloatLayout):
    _change = StringProperty()
    _tnd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self._change = str(self.time)
        self._tnd.text = str(self.time)
        print (self._change)

#Here is where I start referencing Serial Comms, this line is to identify where
#to *send* commands to via a separate identifier.
bone = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)


class XGApp(App):
    time = StringProperty()
    sensor1 = NumericProperty(0)
    sensor2 = NumericProperty(0)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = str(time.asctime())
    arduino = self.arduino
    data = arduino.read(arduino.inWaiting())
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            sensor, value = line.strip().split(' ')
        except:
            print("parse error!")
            continue
        if sensor == 'A':
            self.sensor1 = float(value)
        elif sensor == 'B':
            self.sensor2 = float(value)
        else:
            print("unknown data! {}".format(line))

    def build(self):
        try:
            self.arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
        except Exception as e: print(e)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


xApp = XGApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    xApp.run()
```

**and the .kv:**

```
<ContScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            id: 'TempLabel1'
            text: str(app.sensor1)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2, 'center_y':0.6}

        Label:
            id: 'TempLabel2'
            text: str(app.sensor1)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.6}
```

*later in the .kv:*

```
StackLayout
        orientation: "tb-rl"
        spacing: 15

        Button:
            text: "1"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
            on_press:
                Timer(root, self, 10, [100, 0, 100, 1.75]).start()
                bone.Write('j'.encode())
                print("One Executed")
```

*TempLabel1 and TempLabel2* are the two labels i'd like updated from the sensors.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible. But you are missing a few things.

You are trying to connect to the serial port *after* running your app, that won't work as your app will be stopped when you arrive there. Instead, you want to do this part while your app runs. I would do the try/except to connect to arduino in app.build.

```
def build (self):
    try:
        self.arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
    exept:
        print("unable to connect to arduino :(")

    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
    return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
```

then, you want to check for messages in the update method, but you don't want to block, so you only read the amount of data that is waiting in the buffer.

```
def update(self, *args):
    arduino = self.arduino
    data = arduino.read(arduino.inWaiting())
```

then you do your processing, i assume your data is something like:

```
A value
B value
```

in such case, you can parse it and update the corresponding variable, something like:

```
def update(self, *args):
    arduino = self.arduino
    data = arduino.read(arduino.inWaiting()) 
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            sensor, value = line.strip().split(' ')
        except:
            print("parse error!")
            continue
        if sensor == 'A':
            self.sensor1 = float(value)
        elif sensor == 'B':
            self.sensor2 = float(value)
        else:
            print("unknown data! {}".format(line))
```

would do the job, it's a bit simplistic, as it assumes you always get full lines, but it can be improved later if needed (and it seems enough for a lot of cases in my experience).

Now, we need to make sure that our labels notice the changes of values, for this, kivy uses `properties`, which are smarter attributes, you need to declare them on the app class.

```
class XGApp(App):
    sensor1 = NumericProperty(0)
    sensor2 = NumericProperty(0)
```

now, you can make your update display the value directly, through the app instance.

```
<ContScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 50

        Label:
            id: 'TempLabel1'
            text: str(app.sensor1)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2, 'center_y':0.6}

        Label:
            id: 'TempLabel2'
            text: str(app.sensor2)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.6}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I get an error on the label text (text: app.sensor2) saying "ValueError: Label.text accept only str"

Comment: sorry, just fixed the example code (added "str()" around the two text values).

Comment: now I get the error in app class "object has no attribute 'arduino'"

Comment: it probably failed to connect to it, dev/ttyACM0 might not be the correct address, try using `from serial.tools.list_ports import comports` and getting the correct port from `comports()`'s result.

Comment: Updated the code so it's current, confirmed with serial.tools that the port should in fact be  /dev/ttyACM0. So what is going on?

Comment: maybe a permission issue, try raising the exception instead the print message, to see the actual error.

Comment: Ok, so total surprise. I switched the exception line to "except Exception as e: print(e)" and that alone seems to have done something. The program actually started up as normal yet after looking at the traceback I see 'Parse Error' repeating. Huge progress, but something is left to do

Comment: well, i told you what i expected the messages to be formated like, if it's different, you'll obviously need to adapt this code, this answer is more of a guideline than a solution you can apply directly, the specifics depend on your situation.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get the Arduino side to print the values on serial, (ex. '84' on line 1 and '82' on the following line), is this parsing going to pick that up, or how would it differentiate between the two to match to the correct label? If I can simply get the program to pick them up I'll go ahead and mark it checked for you

Comment: You could make the arduino say which sensor it is each time, like i assumed in the example, or you could alternate, but you need to be sure you get them in the right order on the python side, and then use an index and % 2 to decide on which value to save it.

Comment: Sorry, but Index and % 2 just went completely over my head. How does that look?